# Proof of a divisibility property of repunit products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, repunit-numbers

A [repunit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit) is a number that contains only the digit 1 under base 10. Define the $k$-th repunit to be $r(k):=\sum_{i=1}^{k} 10^{i-1}$. Show that
$$\left(\prod_{k=1}^m r(k)\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n r(k)\right) \mid \prod_{k=1}^{m+n}r(k),\quad \forall m,n\in\Bbb N_+$$
where $a\mid b$ means $a$ divides $b$.

Here's what I tried so far: I assumed $m\le n$ and tried investigating $RHS/LHS$ which is
$$\frac{\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+m}r(k)}{\prod_{k=1}^mr(k)}$$

Then I *incorrectly* thought $\{r(k)\}$ are pairwise coprime (which is clearly false say for $r(2), r(4)$), and I proceeded to *incorrectly* conclude that to show $\prod_{k=1}^mr(k)$ divides $\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+m}r(k)$, it suffices to show $\prod_{k=n+1}^{n+m}r(k)$ is divisible by each $r(k),k=1,\cdots,m$, which is easy to prove per se because for each $k\in\{1,\cdots,m\}$ there is a $s\in\Bbb N_+$ such that $sk\in\{n+1,\cdots,n+m\}$, and since $r(k)\mid r(sk)$, we see that the claim holds. However, when I realised the precondition that $\{r(k)\}$ are pairwise coprime is wrong, the claim becomes insufficient to prove the desired result.

Comment: 1/ For a "simple" proof (just quoting known results in the theory), this is the Gaussian binomial coefficient ${{n+m } \choose m} _{x = 10}$ , which is actually a polynomial with integer coefficients, hence letting $ x = 10$ results in an integer.

$\quad$  2/ For each prime $p$, count the number of times it appears in the numerator and denominator by using the multiplciative order of $10$ modulo $p^k$  $\quad$ 3/ Prove by induction on $n+m$ as $f(n+1,m) = f(n,m) + f(n+1, m-1)(10^{n+m+1} - 10^{n+1} ) $.

Comment: 4/ When $10 $ is replaced with a prime, note that this counts the number of subspaces of dimension $n$ in $F_{p} ^{n+m}$, hence is an integer.  $\quad$ 5/ Write it out using Cyclotomic polynomials, and show that it all cancels out (In a sense, this is what 1 does).

Comment: I think your notation is off; maybe you mean $r(k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}10^i$ instead? Because now for $m=n=2$ you have $r(1)=11$ and $r(2)=111$ and so
$$\prod_{k=1}^mr(k)\prod_{k=1}^nr(k)=(11\times111)\times(11\times111)=3^2\times11^2\times37^2,$$
but at $m+n$ you have
$$\prod_{k=1}^{m+n}=11\times111\times1111\times11111=3\times11^2\times37\times41\times101\times271.$$
It also fails at $m=n=1$, as $11\times11$ does not divides $11\times111$, and there are many more instances.

Comment: @Servaes yes you're right, it's an off by one error. Thanks

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks a lot. I didn't know it was actually a thing studied so thoroughly lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $r(k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}10^i$ as otherwise the divisibility does not always hold, see my comment to the question.

---

You already note that $\prod_{k=1}^mr(k)$ divides $\prod_{k=1}^{m+n}r(k)$ and the quotient is $\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n}r(k)$. So it suffices to show that $\prod_{k=1}^nr(k)$ divides $\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n}r(k)$. Of course $$r(k)=\frac{10^{k}-1}{10-1}=[k]_{10},$$
which is known as the $q$-analog of $k$ at $q=10$. Now you want to show that
$[n]_q!:=\prod_{k=1}^n[k]_q$ divides $\tfrac{[m+n]_q!}{[m]_q!}$, or equivalently, that the $q$-binomial coefficient
$$\binom{m+n}{n}_q:=\frac{[m+n]_q!}{[m]_q![n]_q!},$$
is an integer. This is an exercise in elementary algebra; you can show this for any integer $q>1$ in general by induction, with the identity
$$\binom{a}{b}_q=q^b\binom{a-1}{b}_q+\binom{a-1}{b-1}_q,$$
and the fact that $[1]_q=1$ and $[0]_q=0$ for all $q$.